# What are the chances of Monero having a marketplace similar to Openbazaar?

Tags: multisig, forum-funding-system

I realize this would likely need multisig, but are there any plans to add Monero support to Openbazaar? Whether by the OB developers or could we get a FFS to get people working on it to PR the code to the OB repo?

Comment: I think we would need multisig first.

Comment: I'll edit the question but assume by then we have multisig working ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's exactly right, OpenBazaar isn't opposed to other integrations and all PRs will be reviewed. And while multisig is definitely an important part of another cryptocurrency getting accepted, adding in support at all would be a significant undertaking. We've tried to make the code more modular in the 2.0 server version, but Bitcoin is a core aspect of the code and any attempts to add Monero or any other currency shouldn't be taken lightly. If anyone is serious about such an effort, we recommend contacting the devs first in our Slack: http://slack.openbazaar.org"

Answer (score 3):

Now that RingCT has enabled multisig, we may see an implementation of it as soon as this fall.

Once a stable multisig implementation is created, the best course of action will probably be for someone to implement monero support in OpenBazaar, and submit the code to the OB devs via PR. AFAIK, while OB devs have no intentions of adding support for other currencies in the near future, they are open to accepting contributions.

Maintaining a fork of OB or even creating an original competing implementation would introduce fragmentation to what's still a very small ecosystem, and would probably be counterproductive for everyone involved, not to mention being much more labor intensive.

Answer (score 3):

[User 4matter on Reddit reported that the following was written to him in an email by Brian Hoffman and his team](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5d3q3r/is_possible_to_do_an_openbazaar_with_monero/da1hq27/):

> So the app is really only going to be able to implement one crypto currency at a time. Managing multiple crypto wallets in the same app is way more complexity than we want to do. So if you wanted it to support monero it would likely have to be a specific monero fork.
>
> Specifically you would need monero wallet code that implements this interface:
>
> https://github.com/OpenBazaar/openbazaar-go/blob/master/bitcoin/wallet.go
>
> And also a means of getting the fiat exchange rates for monero which implements this interface:
>
> https://github.com/OpenBazaar/openbazaar-go/blob/master/bitcoin/exchangerates.go
>
> Then you would need to initialize the Wallet and ExchangeRates in openbazaard.go with your implementations of those things. As far as I know that's all you would need to do.
>   We haven't yet built most of the UI but it's likey the UI wont show listings denominated in a currency other than what the server accepts.
>
> So monero listings would probably only show as visible for those running a monero fork.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is very likely.

Decentralized marketplaces are the next step in evolution of marketplaces. Similarly when Napster was replaced first by other centralized programs and then by torrents. In this analogy Napster=SilkRoad, current dark-net-markets=centralized programs and torrent=decentralized marketplaces.
This is trend, that cannot be stopped. Once the idea is out, it is just the question of time.

See slides from this presentations for more on this:
http://slides.com/nethemba/how-governments-push-forward-security-of-cryptomarkets#/

Here is another overview and comparison of some decentralized marketplaces that are being developed or already used:

http://syscoin.org/in-depth-look-at-the-syscoins-decentralized-marketplace-and-comparing-it-to-the-competition/
(this comparison might not be objective, as it is from one of the markets authors)

OpenBazaar is not the only decentralized marketplace. Monero is very solid cryptocurrency with the best-in-class privacy, and therefore it is very likely that it will be used in some decentralized marketplace sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Monero support was added to OpenBazaar in December of 2016: https://www.openbazaar.org/blog/openbazaar-1-1-10-released-purchase-with-ether-monero-and-more-via-shapeshift-io-integration/